# Why do I get a command not found message when I open a terminal?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

When I run a new terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, [it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEY66.jpg) this text:

```
Команда «rbenv» не знайдена, але може бути встановлена ​​з:

sudo apt install rbenv
```

How do I fix the problem, so that message no longer appears?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It's not clear what the exact problem is. Is it something to do with the language displayed? Please [edit] your question to add more details about the problem.

Comment: So, it work in file `~/.bashrc` was line with rbenv`s paths, after destroy it everything works. TY

Answer (score 2):

Your `~/.bashrc` contains a line calling `rbenv`, but it isn’t installed on your system. Either remove the line or install the software as suggested and the message will cease to appear.